# How to demonstrate this?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I've a question and it is:

Evaluate ${\partial^2z \over \partial u^2}+{\partial^2z \over \partial v^2}$, if ${\partial^2z \over \partial x^2}+{\partial^2z \over \partial y^2}=0$ and $z=z(x,y)$, $x=e^u cos v$ and $y=e^u sin v$
I can't solve it because I don't know how to begin and which one I derive first.

Comment: use the chain rule

Comment: What is the function $z$ with I have to derive? I can't see it. Could you tell me how I do it

Comment: the function is $z=z(x,y)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the chain rule,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}&=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\\
&=(e^u \cos v)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+(e^u \sin v)\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u^2}&=\frac{\partial }{\partial u}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\right)\\
&=\frac{\partial }{\partial u}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+ \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\right)^2+  \frac{\partial }{\partial u}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}+ \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\right)^2
\end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I still do not understand what I need to do to find the answer. I have to derive $e^u cos v$ with respect to $x$, but it does not have any $x$. Sorry about that, but I'm not understanding this problem.This is a question-challenge of my Calculus II book .

Comment: No problem.  You'll get it.  Note that $z(x,y)$ is a function of both $x$ and $y$.  And both $x(u,v)=e^u \cos v$ and $y(u,v)=e^u \sin v$ are functions of both $u$ and $v$.  By the way, this exercise will be a bit lengthy, so just persevere and you will be able to find the correct answer.

Comment: Ok. I've a doubt: For $x=e^u cos u$, the derivative $\partial x \over \partial u$ is equal to $e^u cos u$?

Comment: But you had the partial derivative correct!!

Comment: ok. Check this derivatives with I've find: ${\partial x \over \partial u}=e^u cosv$, ${\partial x \over \partial v}=-e^u sinv$, ${\partial y \over \partial u}=e^u sinv$ and ${\partial y \over \partial v}=e^u cosv$. It's correct?

Comment: Yes!  Now you have it!!  Well done.

Comment: What rule you used to determinate $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u^2}=\frac{\partial }{\partial u}(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u})$?

Comment: Thanks!!! A anchieved the answer! Muito obrigado!!! You're saved the day.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.